# Show names of created virtual consoles in screen (Linux)

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

How can I tell screen to always show created virtual console names in the bottom. I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [caption](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Caption.html) command with several Screen-specific [escape codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes).

For example, try appending this to your `.screenrc`, and restartng `screen`:

```
caption always "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%< %=%d.%m %c"
```